# jquery click event.. Do I need an each loop?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, each

I have this code within a Wordpress template is used within an image gallery, so each image, when clicked shows a pop up which can be clicked on to go to a contact page about that product.

```
$("#cycle div.i").click(function () {// show pohelp 
    $('quickinfo').hide();
    var quickinfo = '#'+ $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(quickinfo).css('left', parseInt(offset.left-90)+'px').css('top', parseInt(offset.top-205)+'px').removeClass('l j hideme');
});
```

The issue is that the image that has shown up will not remove when another image is clicked.
I would like only one popped up more info image to show at once.

Comment: Looks like your 'quickinfo' selector is wrong, isn't it a class instead: `$('.quickinfo').hide();`  But then you use a variable quickinfo which is using an ID, quite confusing. Provide all relevant code (HTML) if you wish more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('quickinfo').hide();` is not working as it selects an invalid element.

You just add class to all the images.  For instance, add a class "image_gallery" like so:

```
<img class="image_gallery">
<img class="image_gallery">
```

Then use that class to select them as `$('.image_gallery).hide()` instead of your invalid `$('quickinfo').hide();`

```
$("#cycle div.i").click(function () {
    $('image_gallery').hide();
    var quickinfo = '#'+ $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(quickinfo).css('left', parseInt(offset.left-90)+'px').css('top', parseInt(offset.top-205)+'px').removeClass('l j hideme');
});
```